# mongo updateMany с дополнительной логикой

Tags: node.js, mongodb

1. Есть массив с id документов коллекции которым надо сделать update:  `var id = [1, 2, 3];`
2. Есть одинаковые данные которые надо изменить в update `var data = { status: 'done', active: 'false' };`

Чтобы обновить все надо просто выполнить на nodejs один раз:

```
collection.updateMany({_id: { $in: id }}, {$set: data });
```

Но потребовалось обновить ещё одно поле в документах, значение для которого берется из логики на nodejs, например, так:

```
var id = [{ id: 1, orderId: 45 }, { id: 2, orderId: 100 }, { id: 3, orderId: 110 }];
```

Нужно обновить документы с id из массива данными соответственно orderId и переменной data.

Напрашивается такое решение:

```
id.forEach(el => {
   collection.updateOne({ _id: el.id }, { $set: {...data, ...{ orderId: el.orderId }}})})
});
```

Возможна ли реализация с обновлением одним запросом из nodejs, чтобы не делать 100 update в цикле, например, если в массиве id будет 100 элементов

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512953/mongodb-multi-update-with-different-value